# Where are the links of the saved pages of Opera Mini are stored in Android?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, opera-mini

I have an Android 2.3 Gingerbread and have installed Opera Mini. I used it to save many useful pages for offline viewing and I want to save the links of the pages in a text file. So I need to find the place where the links of the saved pages are stored.

Comment: Have you tried looking in your Downloads folder (usually `/sdcard/Downloads`)?

Comment: You need to view the list of saved pages? Or the location of the saved pages in the sdcard?

Answer (score 2):

OP seems to confuse Saved Pages feature with Bookmarks. Address of a saved page (or any page viewed in Opera Mini) is copy / pastable (to anywhere) from the top of your screen. Whole point of Saved Pages is they contain the actual page contents as well (OP seems strangely unconcerned about losing this !).

Path to Saved Page data given above may well be correct; or possibly... / mnt / asec / com.opera / lib (or possibly folder "lost+found ?).  Problem is, as stated, the location is inaccessible without fraught rooting procedure (ES File Explorer declares the directories to be empty for example).

My advice to anyone wanting to backup Saved Pages is to copy the addresses into UC Browser & re-save them in .mht format (earlier UC Browsers also saved as .html .txt or .pdf using addons). Pages are then accessible / transferable / viewable on PC etc. Slow & stupid but a guaranteed solution. It also punishes Opera Mini's developers (who are generally admirable) for consistently building in this infuriating anti-functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Saved pages are stored in Opera Mini's private file directory, which is `/data/data/com.opera.mini.android/files/`. They are saved in [Opera Binary Markup Language (OBML)](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-binary-markup-language/), and you will need root privileges in order to access them.

As far as I understand, the links are simply embedded in the .obml file rather than being stored separately anywhere.